# Resizing PVC in Kubernetes With Kubectl edit

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volume-claims

Recently I tried to resize `PersistentVolumeClaim` with help of `Kubectl edit pvc` to increase storage from `10 Gi` to `70 Gi` but it’s giving error:

```
persistentvolumeclaims "myclaim" was not valid:
* spec: Forbidden: spec is iimmutable after creation except resources.requests for bound claims
```

How can I do this with out error with help of `Kubectl edit`.

[Screen of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SVjD.jpg)

Comment: "*... but it’s giving error ....*" - Please [edit] the post and include the error. Also, please include the resource definition as text.

Comment: Please edit your question and add more details, like your environment, how did you create this PVC, did you unbound it before changing?

Comment: As this question is still closed I will provide short answer in comment. `spec` in `PVC` is `immutable` which means you cannot change this value after creation. In PVC you can only change resource requests. `spec is immutable after creation **except resources.requests for bound claims** `  If you need to change storage size, you need to remove this PVC and create another one with storage 70Gi

Comment: @PjoterS its open now

Answer (score 9):

I have verified this on my GKE test cluster which supports [Dynamic Provisioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/). As I mentioned in comments, you are trying to edit `spec` part of [PersistentVolumeClaim](https://gist.github.com/cloudyuga/f9926cd706df0d26fd19c9add15314fb) which is `immutable`, except `resources.requests`.

However, `storage` field path is `spec.resources.requests.storage` and I do not have any issue with editing this. When you are using `kubectl edit` as default it's using `vi editor` which controls might be hard/it's easy for a typo. I guess you accidentally changed more than just `storage` in your example (maybe typo in `selectors`, `labels`).

You can always use another editor like `nano`.
`KUBE_EDITOR="nano" kubectl edit pvc <pvc-name>`

For test Ive used [This YAML](https://gist.github.com/cloudyuga/f9926cd706df0d26fd19c9add15314fb) on GKE cluster.

```
$ kubectl get pvc
NAME               STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
mongodb-pv-claim   Bound    pvc-802714bf-3922-4b41-b70f-97394f252a00   10Gi       RWO            standard       16s
```

Instead of `editing` resource you can also [patch resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#patching-resources).

`kubectl patch pvc <pvc-name> -p '{"spec":{"resources":{"requests":{"storage":"70Gi"}}}}'`

```
$ kubectl patch pvc mongodb-pv-claim -p '{"spec":{"resources":{"requests":{"storage":"70Gi"}}}}'
persistentvolumeclaim/mongodb-pv-claim patched
```

After that, if you will describe `PVC` you can find information like below:

```
Conditions:
  Type                      Status  LastProbeTime                     LastTransitionTime                Reason  Message
  ----                      ------  -----------------                 ------------------                ------  -------
  FileSystemResizePending   True    Mon, 01 Jan 0001 00:00:00 +0000   Fri, 25 Sep 2020 06:40:17 +0000           Waiting for user to (re-)start a pod to finish
 file system resize of volume on node.
```

After while:

```
$ kubectl get pvc
NAME               STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
mongodb-pv-claim   Bound    pvc-802714bf-3922-4b41-b70f-97394f252a00   70Gi       RWO            standard       8m37s
```

Please keep in mind that as per error message, that it's wokring only for `bound claims`.

If `patch` or `edit with nano` won't work for you, please provide your `PVC` yaml.

**EDIT**

As per OP's comment below answer, creating `storageclass` which supports [Dynamic Provisioning](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/#enabling-dynamic-provisioning) resolved this issue.

Comment: May be you are using a dynamic storage class, because according to my search and Kubernetes documentation only A PVC can be edited if the storage class is Dynamic so first i created a dynamic storage class and then edited same pvc smoothly without any error.

Comment: @Aftab I've used GKE so I was using `Dynamic Provisioning`.

Comment: Right, Solved then,

Comment: Hello @Aftab I am also trying to create POD using a PVC which is using a SC. But when I start the pod it gives me below error in my local Virtualbox cluster... did you faced any such problem?

Warning  FailedScheduling  81s (x2 over 82s)  default-scheduler  0/3 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {node-role.kubernetes.io/master: }, that the pod didn't tolerate, 2 node(s) didn't find available persistent volumes to bind.