# PVC Stuck in Resizing -AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-storage, azure-aks, kubernetes-pvc

I edited my pvc for resizing. I tried restarting the statefulset after some time. Now my pvc resizing is stuck for around 3 hours. i tried restarting the statefulset many times. What can i do?

Comment: What kind of storage is the PVC using?

Comment: Can you post the output of `kubectl describe pvc <name>` to your question.

Answer (score 0):

**The reason for getting stuck in resizing PVC is `spec` in `PVC` is immutable which means you cannot change this value after creation. In PVC you can only change resource requests. `spec` is immutable after creation `except resources.requests for bound claims`  If you need to change storage size, you need to remove this PVC and create another one.**

**For more information you can refer this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63965817/resizing-pvc-in-kubernetes-with-kubectl-edit)**

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this command, this might fix your issue.

```
az resource update --ids /subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION-ID>/resourcegroups/<RESOURCE-GROUP>/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/<AKS-CLUSTER-NAME>/agentpools/<NODE-GROUP-NAME>
```